# Material Design Lite (MDL) VS Angular2 Material in Angular2 app

Tags: angular, material-design-lite, angular-material2

There are a few Angular2 tutorials on YouTube and other learning sites, some of which have used **Material Design Lite (MDL)** and some have used the new **Angular2 Material** for demonstration purposes.

Considering that Angular2 Material is still pretty new (currently in Alpha) and limited in the number of components and documentation as compared to MDL, **which would be a better option to implement in Angular2** at this point of time and what are the **pros and cons of each** specific to Angular2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MDL is definitely the one that's better documented (I haven't found any good documentation on Angular2 Material). I think that because of this, MDL is *(currently)* the better choice. The negative of MDL is that it isn't integrated in typescript/angular2.

If you're going to be using MDL components in your Angular 2 component templates, you can extend your component from something like this, to have the MDL components registered: (otherwise MDLs animations will not work, as they depend on the javascript)

```
declare var componentHandler: any;
export class MaterialTemplate {
    ngAfterViewInit(){
        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
    }
}
```

Usage would be something like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    template: `
        <form action="#">
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
        <input value="{{bleh}}" class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1">Text...</label>
        </div>
        <button (click)="action()" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
        create
        </button>
        </form>`
})
export class CreateComponent extends MaterialTemplate {...}
```

Once Angular2 Material is out of alpha and has some documentation, I'd switch to that though.

Answer (score 0):

**Its totally on your use case.**
Will your project be going into production soon, or is there quite some time for it ?
Do you require Customizing the UI Components down to every detail or is it very general purpose ? Ive been researching a lot and since we have a short time to go into production i choose Bootstrap Material Design URL : mdbootstrap.com
Reason : If u use angular material Components, well first off they are in alpha second , my use case is very customized, example would be i am calling rest services to populate even basics like radio,checkboxes.

**Point being**, if you are short on time require heavy customization go with MDL (Even the popular Wijmo 5 ng2 components are using it now) or you could wait and opt for angular2 material.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Angular2-material and MDL, there is also MaterializeCSS which is a CSS Framework based on material design. Their official web site is located at http://materializecss.com

They have much more working components than provided by MDL or Angular2-material, all with examples and documentation.

However, MaterializeCSS is JQuery based, i.e. it needs JQuery to activate the dynamic behaviour of some components. Have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize. This package adds exactly this dynamic behaviour to Angular2 apps. Just Import the `MaterializeDirective` in your Angular2 component and it should work.